# Client Authentication failed in Paypal sandbox mode

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to add Paypal's smart buttons to my website.
I followed the tutorial here:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/

Anyway, this is the code in my `payment.html` file:

```
<!-- End of Body content -->
</body>
    <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=sb&currency=ILS&locale=he_IL&vault=true"></script>

  <script>
  paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '49.99'
          }
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
        alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
        // Call your server to save the transaction
        return fetch('../paypal.php', {
          method: 'post',
          headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            orderID: data.orderID
          })
        });
      });
    }
  }).render('#pay');
</script>
```

This is my `paypal.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Sample;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//1. Import the PayPal SDK client that was created in `Set up Server-Side SDK`.
use Sample\PayPalClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Orders\OrdersGetRequest;

class GetOrder
{

  // 2. Set up your server to receive a call from the client
  /**
   *You can use this function to retrieve an order by passing order ID as an argument.
   */
  public static function getOrder($orderId)
  {

    // 3. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
    $client = PayPalClient::client();
    $response = $client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId));
    /**
     *Enable the following line to print complete response as JSON.
     */
//   echo json_encode($response->result);
    print "Status Code: {$response->statusCode}\n";
    print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
    print "Order ID: {$response->result->id}\n";
    print "Intent: {$response->result->intent}\n";
    print "Links:\n";
    foreach($response->result->links as $link)
    {
      print "\t{$link->rel}: {$link->href}\tCall Type: {$link->method}\n";
    }
    // 4. Save the transaction in your database. Implement logic to save transaction to your database for future reference.
    print "Gross Amount: {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->currency_code} {$response->result->purchase_units[0]->amount->value}\n";

    // To print the whole response body, uncomment the following line
    // echo json_encode($response->result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  }
}


if (!count(debug_backtrace()))
{
    $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($request_body,true);
$id=$json["orderID"];
  GetOrder::getOrder($id, true);
}
```

and this is my `paypal_loader.php` file:

```
<?php

namespace Sample;

use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\PayPalHttpClient;
use PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\SandboxEnvironment;

ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // or error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');

class PayPalClient
{
    /**
     * Returns PayPal HTTP client instance with environment that has access
     * credentials context. Use this instance to invoke PayPal APIs, provided the
     * credentials have access.
     */
    public static function client()
    {
        return new PayPalHttpClient(self::environment());
    }

    /**
     * Set up and return PayPal PHP SDK environment with PayPal access credentials.
     * This sample uses SandboxEnvironment. In production, use LiveEnvironment.
     */
    public static function environment()
    {
        $clientId = getenv("CLIENT_ID") ?: "myclientidhere";
        $clientSecret = getenv("CLIENT_SECRET") ?: "mysecrethere";
        return new SandboxEnvironment($clientId, $clientSecret);
    }
}
```

I get the javascript alert ("transaction completed by....") on the payment.html after using the sandbox account to pay and the payment is actually being completed the problem is when I try to verify it on the server side the response I'm getting from the paypal.php is:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught BraintreeHttp\HttpException: {&quot;error&quot;:&quot;invalid_client&quot;,&quot;error_description&quot;:&quot;Client Authentication failed&quot;} in C:\xampp\htdocs\firstGear\schoolcontrol\vendor\braintree\braintreehttp\lib\BraintreeHttp\HttpClient.php:185
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\firstGear\schoolcontrol\vendor\braintree\braintreehttp\lib\BraintreeHttp\HttpClient.php(97): BraintreeHttp\HttpClient-&gt;parseResponse(Object(BraintreeHttp\Curl))
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\firstGear\schoolcontrol\vendor\paypal\paypal-checkout-sdk\lib\PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\AuthorizationInjector.php(37): BraintreeHttp\HttpClient-&gt;execute(Object(PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\AccessTokenRequest))
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\firstGear\schoolcontrol\vendor\paypal\paypal-checkout-sdk\lib\PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\AuthorizationInjector.php(29): PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\AuthorizationInjector-&gt;fetchAccessToken()
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\firstGear\schoolcontrol\vendor\braintree\braintreehttp\lib\BraintreeHttp\HttpClient.php(64): PayPalCheckoutSdk\Core\AuthorizationInjector-&gt;inject(Object(PayPalChecko in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\firstGear\schoolcontrol\vendor\braintree\braintreehttp\lib\BraintreeHttp\HttpClient.php</b> on line <b>185</b><br />
```

I tripled check my client_id and client_secret, and can't figure out for hours now where's the problem in the code as it's pretty much copy pasted from paypal's website.

Would appreciate your help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am getting the same error as you.

Comment: I had the same issue now, I don't know why yet, but it helped avoiding the helping classes and call PayPalHttpClient directly in my code. Haven't checked further, but this saved my night.